# Getting error for checkbox binding in knockout during serialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, serialization, knockout.js

I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('checkbox') does not support selection.

on:

```html
<div class="panel-heading paddingRight20px">
  <input style="position: absolute;" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelectedCoverage" />
</div>
```

When I am debugging the code, I found that it was giving this error when I am trying to serialize the viewmodel (which has the `IsSelectedCoverage` observable).

Ajax call where I am serializing:

```
self.finish = function () {
    debugger;
    var CorrespondenceData = ko.toJSON(self);
    $.ajax({
        url: endPoints.Finish + '/' + self.MemberId(),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: CorrespondenceData,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        beforeSend: function () {
            startSpinner();
        }
    })
```

I am not sure if this is due to serializing the model.

Comment: You'll need to include some more code and/or sample data, given your current question we are probably not able to reproduce your situation.

Comment: Read this ko.toJSON(self); twice hope you will understand the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jeroen says, we'd need to see at least your view-model to determine the cause, but here's something which might help: you're relying on the out-of-the-box serialisation provided by Knockout, but you can override this to be more certain of what's being returned.

If you add a function called `toJSON` to your view-model then this will be called by Knockout (although you can just as easily call it yourself). This then gives you more fine-grained control over what's being serialised and how.
[[source](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html)]

In this `toJSON` function, if you don't want to monotonously write out the whole JSON string then you can build a very simple object and call `toJSON` on that.

For example, let's say you're view-model has 15 observables but that the server is interested in only 2 of these, `firstName` and `lastName`:

```
var toJSON = function() {
    return JSON.stringify({
                                firstName: this.firstName(),
                                lastName: this.lastName()
                          });
```

*Where `this.firstName()` gets the value of the `firstName` observable on the same view-model.*

Calling `toJSON` or `ko.toJSON` on that view-model will now return a JSON string with only those two properties

It may be that you have some extraneous property on your view-model which is sending something unexpected back to the server.

Comment: Or use a mapping function